# Is the standard bounded metric $\overline d(x,y) = \min\{d(x,y), 1\}$ well defined in terms of meet operator on metric topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, definition, lattice-orders

In these [notes](http://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/uniformmetric.pdf) I came across a curious notation

Let $\overline d(x,y) = \min\{d(x,y), 1\}$ is a well known standard bounded metric on a metric space $(X,d)$

> However, in the notes in linked, it was rewritten as: 
>   Given any metric space $(X, d)$
>   $\overline d(x,y) = d(x,y) \wedge1$, where $x\wedge y = \min\{x,y\}$

Is this way of writing well defined?

I am asking because on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet article , it says:

> In a partially ordered set P, the join and meet of a subset S are
>   respectively the supremum (least upper bound) of S, denoted ⋁S, and
>   infimum (greatest lower bound) of S, denoted ⋀S. In general, the join
>   and meet of a subset of a partially ordered set need not exist; when
>   they do exist, they are elements of P.

Joint and meet are defined in terms of $\sup$ and $\inf$...which does not necessarily  exist.

Can someone explain why it is formulated in terms of a single $\min$ in the definition above instead of $\inf$ in the definition of meet? How does being a metric space guarantee we have a $\min$?

Or maybe I am reading too much into this and $\wedge$ is not the meet operator. 
 I know nothing about lattice theory if that helps.

Comment: It is just the minimum of the two quantities. The symbol $\lor$ is similarly used for $\max$.

Comment: @copper.hat Got it silly me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The poset here is just $\mathbb{R}$.  The meet symbol here is being used as a binary operator, so $x\wedge y$ means the same thing as $\bigwedge\{x,y\}$ (much the same as $x\cup y$ means a union of two sets $x$ and $y$ but $\bigcup X$ means the union of all the elements of $X$).  So $d(x,y)\wedge 1$ means the infimum of the set containing the two real numbers $d(x,y)$ and $1$, which is just the lower of the two (in general, if a set has a least element, that is its infimum).

Comment: Thanks, was not use to this way of writing...